# Not sure how to set seo friendly url by htaccess and php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm getting same problem while I tried multisite from last three days but didn't get any positive response. I know I'm posting duplicated question but in my case nobody describe question same to my problem..

My project almost completed but the problem is urls seo friendly. I'm not able to get clean url with the same article on result page as shown in screenshot bellow.

**My htaccess code is**:

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 


RewriteRule ^article/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)?$ article.php?article_link=$1
RewriteRule ^article/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ article.php?article_link=$1
```

**My index.php code**:

```html
   if(mysqli_num_rows($run) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
     $id = $row['id'];
     $date = $row['date'];
     $title = $row['title'];
     $author = $row['author'];
     $author_image = $row['author_image'];
     $image = $row['image'];
     $categories = $row['categories'];
     $tags = $row['tags'];
     $views = $row['views'];
    $article_link =$row['article_link'];

 ?>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="article/<?php echo $article_link;?>"><img src="uploads/art_img/<?php echo $image;?>" width="100%" height="250px" alt=""></a>
   </div>
```

**My article code is:**

```html
  if(isset($_GET['article_link'])){
    $article_link = $_GET['article_link'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE status='publish' and title=$article_link";

    $run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($run) > 0){
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run);

      $id = $row['id'];
      $date = $row['date'];
  // $day = $date['mday'];
  // $month = $date['month'];
  // $year = $date['year'];
      $image = $row['image'];
      $title = $row['title'];
      $author = $row['author'];
      $author_image = $row['author_image'];
      $article_data = $row['article_data'];
      $article_link = $row['article_link'];

    }
    else{
      header('Location: index');
    }
  }
```

**Result**
[image: Result Page]

**Thanks for your help, I'll appreciate your questions about my codes**

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: I'm using localhost xampp and .htaccess is located in main project directory, same where index.php, article.php etc files are existed..

Comment: and I'm not sure about  $_GET['article_link'] in article.php page where visitors will come from index.php. please you can review. those portion of code. Thanks for helping.